# Add a class to parent element when Bootstraps 4 dropdown is open?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I was wondering how can I add a class to parent element when Bootstraps Dropdown is open?

HTML :

```
<div class="item-content">

          <div class="block-handle">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item draggable-trigger" href="">2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

JS

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
  });
```

So what I'm trying to do is to add active class to div class="item-content"

Comment: What is your error message? Could you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `parents` in jQuery instead of `parent` since it's not a direct parent.

https://codeply.com/go/vObdBWFwnL

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).parents('.item-content').addClass('active');
});
```

Most likely you'll also want to handle the `hide` event...

```
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).parents('.item-content').removeClass('active');
});
```